# Timing when training models using caret in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, r-caret

I am developing a model for classification, and am training models using cross-validation via `caret`. I would like to get timings for each model (i.e. combination of tuning parameters/row in the tuning grid, `caret::train(..., tuneGrid = tgrid)`).

I thought this would be a built-in functionality, but couldn't find any info. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Try `microbenchmak` or `Sys.time()`

Comment: I think you will need to build a custom model to return this info. I don't think caret has this inbuilt but perhaps wait for topepo to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is documented in `?caret::train`:

```r
caret::train(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, method = "lm")$times
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> $everything
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.636   0.008   0.644 
#> 
#> $final
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.001   0.000   0.001 
#> 
#> $prediction
#> [1] NA NA NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I only just now saw you comment. Thanks, this is a first step but I was looking for individual timings (like `$final`, but for each row of of the tuning grid).